# Is there a better way to validate in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my model I have validations that check for presence of the "password" and "password_confirmation" fields. While creating the model, the validations run fine. But during updating the model, even while updating a group of specific fields, validations seem to be called on the whole model. And as I dont pass in the "password" and "password_confirmation" fields every time, the validation fails.

At first my thought was to validate those two fields only "on :create" but I want to give the option to update the password as well. In which case the validations wont be called during update of those fields.

So, is there a way to handle this problem?

The following is my model:

```
    class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
      mount_uploader :image, ProfileImageUploader

      EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
      PASS_REGEX = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}\z/

      validates :email, presence: {message: "Email cannot be blank!", on: :create}, format: {with: EMAIL_REGEX, message: "Email invalid!"}
      validate :unique_email?, on: :create
      validates :password, presence: {message: "Password cannot be blank!"}, confirmation: {message: "Passwords do not match!"}, format: {with: PASS_REGEX, message: "Password invalid!"}
      validates :password_confirmation, presence: {message: "Retype password!"}
      validates :fullname, presence: {message: "Name cannot be empty!"}

before_save :encrypt_password

def authenticate pass
    new_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret pass, self.password_salt
    if  new_hash === self.password_hash
      return true
    end
    false
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret password, password_salt
    end
  end

    end
```

Comment: I think you don't need validation on password_confirmation when you already are using bcrypt-ruby since it by default check for password_confirmation, also, you already have password_confirmation in password validation. I think this is it, you can use `has_secure_password` instead I guess?

Comment: Haha I can't believe I came across this question, I was just wondering the same thing earlier today.
Check out this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations that's pretty much what I did except adapted to my project.

Comment: @Xerif917 That was perfect! Exactly what I needed. Could you put it up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

[**Conditional Validations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)

Was going to suggest you use some sort of [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), as follows (then I read the comments):

```
#app/models/consumer.rb
class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      validates :password_confirmation, presence: {message: "Retype password!"}, if: Proc.new {|a| a.password.present? }
end
```

This is the best I can provide for your particular situation - I've not created a `password` signup / authentication procedure myself (always relied on other classes), so if you wanted to use `has_secure_password` etc - I'll have to update my answer to help

Comment: The password_confirmation part itself is not the problem. The problem is that both password and password_confirmation are only used in two cases 'create' and 'update password' and updating other values in the model might not mean updating password.